# Variable inside a javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've looked at a lot of similar questions about this kind of problem but they haven't solved my problem...

This is the string that I've to match: "|6[1]|" where the "6" is a variable that I've to put inside the regexp.

I've tried to create one (pid is the variable that contain the number):

```
var filter = new RegExp("/\|"+pid+"[\d*\]\|/");
```

It's look not working.. tryed with chrome console

[image]

Comment: Use a string without delimiters, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: i need delimteres in my string...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you construct a regular expression from a string you do not need the `/` delimiters:

```
var filter = new RegExp("\|"+pid+"[\d*\]\|");
```

The `/` token is used to signify the start/end of a regular expression literal to the parser, much like the `"` and `'` tokens signify the start/end of a string literal. In this case you're using a string literal so you don't need the regexp literal delimiters.

Your actual regex doesn't work because:

- You've missed the escape character off the opening square bracket
- You need to escape literal backslashes when building a regex from a string

So the working code should be:

```
var filter = new RegExp("\\|"+pid+"\\[\\d*\\]\\|");
//                       ^         ^^ ^   ^  ^ Add in these backslashes
```